# Ext JS: Adding listener to a Picker component in order to disable a separate button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add a listener to my School component which is a column inside a grid. School's **editor** field's xtype extends Ext JS Picker. Basically, the listener will have a function that sets **bindBool** to true when a classroom value is bound.

The grid:

```
 xtype: 'grid',
            scrollable: 'y',
            maxHeight: 300,
            margin: 10,
            sortable: false,
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                pluginId: 'gridEditor'
```

The editor

```
{
  header: 'School',
  width: 300,
  dataIndex: 'classroom',
  renderer: function(value) {
      return value.classroomString;
  },
  editor: {
      xtype: 'classroomfield',
      bind: {
          value: '{classroom}'
          }
      }
}
```

The Zulu button:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    buttons: [{
        style: 'margin-right: 30px',
        text: 'Zulu',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-upload',
        handler: 'xray',
        bind: {
                disabled: '{bindBool}'
        }
    }]
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you';re asking. Why do you think it should be any different?

Comment: When the data in the grid cell is changed from null, I want the button to be enabled. I do not want to actually write code to update the value in the button.

Answer (score -1):

in your viewModel :

```
formulas : {
    bindBool : {
       get : function(get){
           var class = get('classroom')
           return Ext.isEmpty(class) ? false : true;
        }
    }
}
```